# Setting up external authorized_keys on Google Compute

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am moving from AWS and I am using ansible for deployments to a Google Cloud compute instance. I am trying to setup a few users on the box with authorized keys. This used to work for AWS but seems like user management is a little different for Google Compute. Here's what I'm doing.

Created a ssh-key locally. Put this key (public) in ansible files and copying this to a new user created (using ansible) in `/home/deploy/.ssh/authorized_keys`

I'm still not able to login using this key from my local box.

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/deploy_rsa deploy@<host>
```

Is there a list of users that are allowed to login to the box? Can I only configure the users to login to box from cloud console?

**EDIT**

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/deploy_rsa deploy@<host>
... skipped some logs here ....
    Here's SSH logs from client side:
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug2: key: /Users/ankit/.ssh/gcloud-rsa (0x7ff1d16105e0),
    debug2: key: /Users/ankit/.ssh/deploy_rsa (0x0), explicit
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
    debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
    debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/ankit/.ssh/gcloud-rsa
    debug3: send_pubkey_test
    debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: Trying private key: /Users/ankit/.ssh/deploy_rsa
    debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:h+yezPKOVjeA2ZKOAN/1r1GRe2s1nyGKwG6wobm+Vh0
    debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
    debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
    Permission denied (publickey).
```

The other key the client is picking is from `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798431/error-creating-vm-instance-in-google-compute-engine/37802599 Note that you might suffer random internet egress charges if you open up too many ports recklessly. As @Dagang says, just open up port 22 (2nd of the 3 rules in the link)

Comment: Hi @Salmonstrikes I don't think the issue is with networking. It let's me ssh from the primary user. It only blocks the second user that I configure on the box manually. It appears to be an issue with how VM handles authentication (sshd pam?)

Comment: Can you check /home/deploy/.ssh/authorized_keys actually exist? I tried creating a new user on the remote host, but turned out its home directory was not even created somehow.

Comment: I'm not sure if the directory was created, my script is configured to create a directory if it doesn't exist. So it exists now.  And it also created the authorized_keys file with the right permissions and owner.

Comment: You want the facility to have multiple user access for vms, is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, but also the ability to configure this programmatically / via scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Ansible, hope the following documentation help [Connecting to Instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance), [Adding and Removing SSH Keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys), [Creating User Accounts for Linux Instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/user-accounts/)

BTW, it's also possible due to the firewall settings. In non-default networks, tcp:22 is not allowed by default.

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with adding and removing keys using the console. Instead I want to use the linux concept of authorized_keys: http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

So I want to create a few users with specific authorized keys. I'm able to ssh into the system from my primary sshkey I've setup, it's not an issue with network. I want to be able to create more such users using ansible (not via console)

Comment: Did you check /var/log/secure or /var/log/auth.log?

Comment: I looked up /var/log/auth.log, I didn't get much there on failure other than:
`Aug  3 20:29:42 instance-1 sshd[8011]: Connection closed by 71.198.45.230 [preauth]`

It seems like Google has it's own PAM module or somehow is controlling ssh that restricts me from creating a new passwordless ssh-user. I also modified the authorized_keys from after setting it from Google Console. But then it automatically got switched to old version I set from Console (who is doing that?)

Comment: If the issue would be server side then I would expect some more details in the auth.log. You could check client side by adding the -v parameter to ssh.

Comment: Added those logs in my question, it seems to be standard publickey denied permission.